# Sending emails not working after updating to Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I bought a **php** script a while back when **php5** and **codeigniter 1.0** were the thing. Now I come back to the script and had to upgrade to **Codeigniter 3**, now sending **emails** to my clients **does not work**. I looked at the code and can't figure out how the Send_mail.php gets the data from the Ajax.php controller. I would appreciate it if you guys could take a look at it. I know it looks like a bulky code, I will try to strip all the unnecessary junk.

The layout is as follows:

```
  View           Controller      Controller
```

v_sendmail.php  __ Controller1 _____ Controller2

**Controller1**

Opens the socket connection and sends header info to controller2 to initiate the emailing process.
This is the content to be to be sent to controller2:

```
POST ssl://mywebsite.com/index.php/controller2/sendMailnow 
HTTP/1.0 Host:www.mywebsite.com Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
boundary=AaB03x Content-length: 653 --AaB03x Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="user_id" 2 --AaB03x*
```

**Controller 2**

```
    Starts the emailing process to send emails
```

**The issue I see is that Controller2 never gets initialized. If I type the whole URL (https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/controller2/sendMailnow) I see some action in the server logs but nothing from controller to controller**

Answer (score 0):

**Well it turns out my CI3 setup does not want to get the array data like:**

```
 $data['user_id'] = $this->input->post('user_id');
 $data['user_name'] = $this->input->post('user_name');
```

**Instead I had to get the data this way:**

```
 $userid = $this->input->post('user_id');
 $username = $this->input->post('user_name');
```

Now, Controller2 is able to set all the necessary stuff and send emails to all my customers without having to open the controller through the browser.